# Identical list shuffling doesn't work as function // Python

Tags: python, shuffle

I am currently trying to write a simple shuffle function that shuffles two lists identically. I have got it working outside of a function but as soon as I add it in, it just prints the list normally. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong or point me in the right direction? Im sure it's something simple.

The first snippet of code is what I am trying to do, and the second is what currently works.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Cheers

```
import random
ARRAYQ = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
ARRAYA = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]

def shuffle(list1, list2):
    enclosed = list(zip(list1, list2))
    random.shuffle(enclosed)
    list1, list2 = zip(*enclosed)
    return list1, list2

shuffle(ARRAYQ, ARRAYA)
print(ARRAYQ)
print(ARRAYA)
```

.

```
import random
ARRAYQ = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
ARRAYA = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]

enclosed = list(zip(ARRAYQ, ARRAYA))
random.shuffle(enclosed)
ARRAYQ, ARRAYA = zip(*enclosed)

print(ARRAYQ)
print(ARRAYA)
```

Comment: Because you are just calling `shuffle`, you are not assigning the result back.

Comment: @user3764893 Thanks. Fixed it with this `ARRAYQ, ARRAYA = shuffle(ARRAYQ, ARRAYA)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at first snippet. It prints list normally because you print variables declared before function.

Should be:

```
import random
ARRAYQ = ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4"]
ARRAYA = ["A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"]

def shuffle(list1, list2):
    enclosed = list(zip(list1, list2))
    random.shuffle(enclosed)
    list1, list2 = zip(*enclosed)
    return list1, list2

list1, list2 = shuffle(ARRAYQ, ARRAYA)
print(list1)
print(list2)
```